# Conga Composer does not open from Lightning Experience button

Tags: lightning-experience, conga

I have a Detail Page Button on the Opportunity object that opens a url for conga composer. this is the button's code:

```
https://composer.congamerge.com
?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}
&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290}
&Id={!Opportunity.Id}
&Culture=he-IL
&ReportId=00O80000003XawR
```

On classic Salesforce this button opens a new window with conga and all is well.
When I move my UI to lightning experience, this button does not work - I get this error:

> Invalid session or the session has expired. (Lock IPs may be enabled.)

[image]

I have searched for this error message and came to a few web pages ([Conga web site](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/00Troubleshooting_Composer/Composer_Error_Messages/Your_Salesforce_session_has_expired_or_the_Salesforce_API_Servers_are_offline._INVALID_SESSION_ID_or_SERVER_URL_(Release_7,_Release_8)), [Salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h0CiAAI)) that explain to do :

1. Ensure "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" is NOT enabled
2. Ensure the user running the solution has "API Enabled" on their Profile
3. Ensure you have not reached your maximum API request limit
4. Check to see if your Salesforce server is down

Now all of  these settings are ok in my user and profile and org, also - in classic it works perfect.

I have also checked the URL that is generated from the button - it is the same from classic and LEX UI:

```
https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html?
sessionId=mysamesessionid&
serverUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fna28.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2FSoap%2Fu%2F29.0%2F&
Id=0061A0000139JpE&
Culture=he-IL&
ReportId=00O80000003XawR
```

Why doesn't the conga button work from LEX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conga's support site indicates that the session id button doesn't work in lightning, and that the oauth form must be configured and used. 
[composer button help](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Getting_Started_with_Composer/Composer_Basics/06_Anatomy_of_a_Conga_Composer_Button)

Comment: One additional item to consider, you cannot use Report Data in Lightning as you cannot Export Reports.  For any related data, you will also need to migrate your reports to SOQL queries

Comment: Does this fix work in professional edition as it doesn't have access to VF/Apex?  It doesn't seem to recognize the URL I create based off of the info in the link here.

Comment: Link broken and I can't find an update. This is a good example of why it's important to relate the relevant information _here_. A quote and bit of instruction would've kept the answer alive.

Comment: Here is the details from the original link: 
OAuth (Open Authorization) is a different security protocol that is required for all Conga Composer buttons created in the Salesforce Lightning user interface. The Base URL of an OAuth button looks like this:

/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer
?serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_370}
&id=
The &Id= parameter (or &id= in the OAuth button) defines your master object – the Salesforce® object from which you will launch your Composer solution. The value of this parameter will always be the ID of your master object.

Answer (score -1):

Conga Documentation:

> Disable the "Lock IP Address" setting for hosted AppExchange
> applications.
>
> 1. Navigate to Salesforce Setup > Administration Setup > Security Controls > Session Settings.
> 2. Ensure that the "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" field is NOT checked.
> 3. Save.
>    Convert your non-OAuth buttons to OAuth buttons for Lightning.
>    You must RESTART all instances of the browser for the setting to take
>    effect.

https://documentation.conga.com/composer/winter-20/your-conga-session-has-expired-143199315.html